# Mixed deployment of Azure Websites using FTP and git

Tags: git, deployment, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I'm building a website using the Azure Websites product, and I've set up the site to deploy via a local git repository. But I use a significant number of static images that I'm loathe to include in my repository. I'd like to deploy my code via git, then upload the images directory via FTP. But since I enabled git deployment on the Azure dashboard, I am only granted ready access to the FTP site.

Is it possible to mix deployment methods in a single Azure website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, enabling git on your Azure site has no bearing on FTP access, and you should be able to upload your images into the site/wwwroot folder. Did you actually run into a read only issue, or were you just guessing that it would become readonly?

If you're actually seeing it be readonly, we would need to investigate what it going on in your specific scenario.

Comment: Thanks David. I will submit a support ticket about the fact that I have read-only FTP access and no SFTP access.

Comment: If you want, you can post on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/home?forum=azuregit and we will help you directly from there. It's best to have it as a public discussion in case someone else runs into a similar thing later.